# php - Display first item from each line in .txt file

Tags: php, arrays, text-files

I have a .txt file which contains lines that follow a standard convention. I can read every line of the .txt file into an array, but I can't split the spaces in each line and put each word into a new array in order to list the first item of each line.

Access.txt

```
2014-03-16 13:57:35.089 -0700 Information 98
2014-03-16 13:57:35.089 -0700 Information 22
2014-03-16 13:57:35.355 -0700 Information 638
2014-03-16 13:57:35.355 -0700 Information 94
```

LogsModel:

```
public function fileGetContents()
{
    $filename = 'C:/Program Files/FileMaker/FileMaker Server/Logs/Access.log';

    // Open the file
    $fp = @fopen($filename, 'r');

    // Add each line to an array
    if ($fp) {
        $lines = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));

        // split each line by " "
        foreach($lines as $line){
            $line_items = explode(" ", $line);

            return $line_items;
        }
    }
}
```

LogsController:

```
public function index()
{
    // load a model, perform an action, pass the returned data to a variable
    $logs_model = $this->loadModel('LogsModel');
    $line_items = $logs_model->fileGetContents();


    // load views.
    require 'application/views/_templates/header.php';
    require 'application/views/home/index.php';
    require 'application/views/_templates/footer.php';
}
```

home/index.php

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($line_items as $item) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $item ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Right now I'm getting ALL the items from the first line...

```
DATE
2014-03-16
13:57:35.089
-0700   
Information 
98
```

What I want to display is the first item from **EACH** line...

```
DATE
2014-03-16
2014-03-16
2014-03-16
2014-03-16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty simple:

```
  $line_items = explode(" ", $lines[0]); //split first line
  echo $line_items[0]; //print first item
```

If you only want one item of one line, why is your method called `fileGetContents()`?  You're trying to return the whole file as one line, constantly in a loop.  Won't work. You need to redesign this method.

Comment: Thank you! Will definitely redesign method, just got stuck on this for too long... Hope this helps others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is inside LogsModel.

**1)** you need to put `return $line_items;` outside your `foreach(...){...}`.

Now it is inside and preventing the `foreach` to finish the first loop and start with a second loop.

**2)** you don't need the whole array of the explosion, only the first bit.

**3)** inside the `foreach` you need to keep adding the first bits to an array.

So in the end, you need to change:

```
    foreach($lines as $line){
        $line_items = explode(" ", $line);

        return $line_items;
    }
```

into:

```
    $line_items = array();
    foreach($lines as $line){
        $tmp = explode(" ", $line);
        $line_items[] = $tmp[0];
    }
    return $line_items;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Explode](https://www.php.net/explode) retunrs an array so you need to return the first part:

```
public function fileGetContents()
{
    $filename = 'C:/Program Files/FileMaker/FileMaker Server/Logs/Access.log';

    // Open the file
    $fp = @fopen($filename, 'r');
  
    $line_items = array();

    // Add each line to an array
    if ($fp) {
        $lines = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));

        // split each line by " "
        foreach($lines as $line){
            $l = explode(" ", $line);
            $line_items[] = $l[0];
        }
    }
   return $line_items;
}
```